# Why my menu isn't displaying in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, category, store-view, menu

Top navigation menu not displaying in my magento. I refreshed cache and made reindexation. I followed many links and made all the possible options provided from the links. Still, it's not showing the menu.
I just have a main menu with a submenu, in the "All stores" already have associated the menu, but even so, the menu is not displayed.

Comment: Did you fix this issue?

Comment: Yes, I reported below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, the database is corrupted by M1 to M2 migration.
To check I created a new main category and I associated it as the main to the store.
And so I used another migration tool, UberTheme worked and this bug was fixed.